Recovering Files from a Bootlooping Samsung Galaxy Stock S20 Ultra
I have a Samsung Galaxy S20 Ultra that I was using and it just rebooted and never stopped.
I've gone into recovery mode and deleted the cache, then got into download mode and uploaded the stock ver 9 binary firmware which it was on using the BL, AP, CP & CSC (CSC_Home), but it is still stuck in the boot loop.  After flashing, it will go past the Samsung logo and then to OneUI, but then crashes after that, then goes back to the boot loop where it shows the Samsung logo and black screen, and then repeats.
I have developer mode turned on, but I don't think I enabled USB debugging because when I tried to use the adb tool and did adb devices, it didn't list anything.
Is there any way to get the files off this by rooting or something?

Have you tried to boot into safe mode?
